# Jenkins can't clone into a private repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

**Please Don't close this thread as I could not find solution via similar questions**

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins-CI (Hosted on AWS EC2, Ubuntu 14.04), with a private repo but getting the following error log on my test build:

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.ccs.neu.edu/CS5500-Spring2017/team7.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/team7_master-JFXDKNF7YKLHDWVSBPWARTJA2O7KU5KHSA5MKXYP6NWMMCP4ODLA # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.ccs.neu.edu/CS5500-Spring2017/team7.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Team 7
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.ccs.neu.edu/CS5500-Spring2017/team7.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://github.ccs.neu.edu/CS5500-Spring2017/team7.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.ccs.neu.edu/CS5500-Spring2017/team7.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1793)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1519)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:512)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1061)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1101)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:221)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Under 'Manage Jenkins -> Configure System' I have Github Server added with API and Credentials I created on Github Personal Access Tokens. This token was added onto Jenkins to test the connection.

Enterprise GitHub server section also has the API and name added correctly.

Testing the connection to my private GitHub account is successful.

I created a test job for build but it fails as it cannot clone into the repo.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That error generally sounds like there's a self-signed certificate being used, or a CA that isn't in the local list of trusted CA roots. However, while the site works fine in Chrome, running an [SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=github.ccs.neu.edu) shows that the intermediate certificates are sent in the wrong order (and the root is redundantly sent). Perhaps Git is sensitive to errors in the certificate chain.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr 

Okay, so I checked cloning the repo manually on my ec2  instance and as well as on my local machine using https and not SSH ( I guess Jenkins uses https clone, that's why) It succeeds on my local machine but fails on ec2, it gives similar error as the one in Jenkins log. **Cloning was not successful**

`git clone https://github.ccs.neu.edu/CS5500-Spring2017/team7.git
Cloning into 'team7'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.ccs.neu.edu/CS5500-Spring2017/team7.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none`

Comment: Ok, so it sounds more like this particular CA isn't in that file, like I mentioned. Also, Jenkins is using https clone, because you've given it an https:// URL. If you give it an SSH clone URL, it will use that.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr

I'm trying to set up a multi branch pipeline and it asks for API endpoint for GitHub server which is `https`, so I cannot use `ssh`. I'm authenticating via Personal Access Token created in GitHub and imported in jenkins

Comment: Okay,

So this was Ubuntu 14.04 error. I migrated to 16.04 and it was all running fine!